# Associate Azure NSG to Azure ARM VM via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I have an existing network security group that I would like to associate to an existing ARM VM network interface using PowerShell.

Can someone please help with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to associate an NSG to an existing ARM VM NIC.

Comment: I did, all I can find is how to do this for Classic VM using the Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupAssociation command.

Comment: Found the solution here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-ps.md

Comment: if that is the answer to your question then try adding it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on Azure GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-ps.md